# Error initializing the application: No such property: session for class: BootStrap

Tags: grails, bootstrapping

How to set user to the session in bootstrap. I am getting the error

```
Error initializing the application: No such property: session for class: BootStrap
```

In bootstrap.groovy

```
class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        session.loggedInUser = "Anantha"

    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Comment: When the bootstrap is run, there is no session.  A session is generated per-user browsing the site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the bootstrap is run, there is no session. A session is generated per-user browsing the site